# iOS StackPanel Equivalent

Tags: ios

In WP7\Silverlight\WPF you have a StackPanel container that will stack its contained items in a specific and predefined orinetation (horizontally\vertically).

Is there an equivalent container for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only equivalent I've been able to find is https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackPanel which is under the MIT license.